# Como instalar mi bootloader( ubuntu y windows)

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Tengo 3 discos(2 dd y 1 ssd) en mi pc,
En uno instale windows 10 modo heredado, y en otro instale ubuntu, el bootloader de ubuntu lo instale en el mimso que se instalo,inicio mi pc pero no me aparece le grub. donde tengo que instalar el bootloader? o como hago para que aparezca el grub?

Nota:
el disco 0 es para almacenamiento
el disco 1 esta ubuntu y su bootloader
el disco 2 esta windows
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que arranques la computadora con un `Live-USB` o un `Live-CD` de `ubuntu` e instales el [**Boot-Repair**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) de la siguiente manera:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Al ejecutar lo anterior en la terminal de `ubuntu` te saldrá una ventana como la siguiente:

[image: Boot Repair]

Dale en el primer botón que dice "**Recommended repair (repairs most frequent problems)**", luego de que el programa haga lo que tenga que hacer reinicias la computadora y ya deberías ver el `grub` correctamente con las opciones para iniciar `windows` o `ubuntu`

Si tienes problemas para ejecutar este comando

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Ejecuta este antes

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde la configuración de la BIOS, tienes que seleccionar que arranque el bootloader de Ubuntu en vez de el de Windows, a veces pasa que instalas Linux, pero el propio instalador no puede cambiar el arranque, tendrás que hacerlo manual.